# Driver and Hardware compatiblity

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hard-drive, lenovo, ssd

I am looking at a laptop and there are two things that I think might not be compatible. It has:

- a dual SLI-Nvidia Gtx 650, *and*
- a hybrid drive 1TBHDD+16GB SSD.

[Here's the laptop.](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=7762559&CatId=3998)

So, I want to know if it would be compatible out of the box or I'd need specific driver or it might not work at all on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.04 has open source Nvidia drivers; you can also select to use the proprietary Nvidia drivers.  Both work reasonably well.  The SSD cache of the hard disk will be transparent to you (and your OS) and will be managed by the hard disk firmware; Ubuntu will just see this as a 1TB hard disk.